Is it possible to delete merge requests?
In GitLab on Drupal.org, module maintainers can close and reopen merge requests.  Is it possible to delete them?
According to the GitLab docs, there should be a Delete button when editing the merge request, but I don't see one.  The docs also note "You must have the Owner role for the project."
Does this mean that it isn't possible to delete merge requests?

On git.drupalcode.org, people who are project owners, maintainers, or co-maintainers cannot delete a merge request.
The GitLab documentation is correct: The Owner role is necessary to delete merge requests. On git.drupalcode.org, that role is not even given to project owners. (I took this screenshot for a project I created.)



That is in line with the definition of project owner given on drupal.org.

Owners have full permissions on the project: make commits, edit the project node, add or remove co-maintainers/maintainers, change the permissions given to each co-maintainer/maintainer, maintain issues, and administer releases. They are maintainers, but differently from the other maintainers, nobody can change the permissions owners have on projects they own.

I take the Administrator account is used by Drupal Association developers, but they would not probably full-fill any request to delete merge requests.

They may if you ask.
